# Project One: IOHK light wallet in the making - where to find the source code?

Tags: wallet, pab, development

There was a [talk at the Cardano summit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbi07kZM_Zk) mentioning the new Cardano light wallet in the works by IOHK and Charles Hoskinson very briefly made a reference to the same project in his latest [Dapps whiteboard talk](https://youtu.be/Yt4Sg6rs80Q?t=2794) (from 46 min 34 s).

Do you know if the source code will be open-sourced? If the source code is already accessible and where? Github doesn't seem to have a repo for it.

I would really love to understand if this wallet could be the MetaMask equivalent in the Cardano ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the wallet or its source code is not yet release.

If you are looking for a metamask equivalent, you might want to check [Nami wallet](https://namiwallet.io/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Nami wallet is interesting but isn't available on mobile and doesn't include a built-in browser unfortunately.

Comment: What is a build-in browser? Also, I'm not sure if there are plans for mobile version of One.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think IOG has announced if it will be or not. It is still in development/testing so maybe that is why. I would guess it will be open sourced based on Emurgo open sourcing their Yoroi wallet: [web](https://github.com/Emurgo/yoroi-frontend) and [mobile](https://github.com/Emurgo/yoroi-mobile).

IOG did say they want this new wallet to be interoperable with other chains so I think if they are taking on MetaMask (also [open source](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-mobile)) they would do the same.

This new light wallet could certainly be the MetaMask equivalent. I think of it similar to the official Algorand Wallet. Although there is a point to be made around the success and innovation of these 3rd party wallets in our space.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be talking about 'Mithril'.

Here is some info as a starting point:
https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2021/10/29/mithril-a-stronger-and-lighter-blockchain-for-better-efficiency/